# Redirect after successful login Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have spring boot application as API in which i use oauth2 for authentication.(the bearer token ...).
In my angular application i have an authentication interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') != null) {
  req = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
  });
} else if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') == null) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  return next.handle(req.clone());
}
return next.handle(req).pipe(
  // we can check the status of the exception. And depending on the status,
  // we can decide what we should do.
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    return throwError(error.error);
  }),
  // We could check the type of object/error to show
  // in our case to send error from backend to front
  tap((succ) => {
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err.status === 500) {
        return next.handle(req.clone());
      }
    }),
);
}
```

an auth guard:

```
canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
const url: string = state.url;
return this.checkLogin(url);

}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
 return this.canActivate(route, state);
}

checkLogin(url: string) {

if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
  return true;
}
this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: { returnUrl: url }} );
return false;
}
```

and finally the login function in my login ts file:

```
onSubmit() {
localStorage.clear();
this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password)
  .subscribe((dataReceived: any) => {
      console.log("test login"+dataReceived)
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', dataReceived.access_token);
      localStorage.setItem('expiredIn', dataReceived.expires_in);
      localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', dataReceived.refresh_token);
      const expireDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * dataReceived.expires_in));
      localStorage.setItem('dateExpiration', expireDate.toString());
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err) {
        this.error = 'login.login_msg';
      }
    });

}
```

On successful login i don't get redirected to home url.(i am sure of the credentials and the success of the login because when i remove '/login' from the url bar i get redirected to homepage).

This is my auth service ts code:

```
  public storedToken: string;
/**
 * constructor
 * @param HttpClient httpClient
 */
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  // set token if saved in local storage
  this.storedToken = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
}
redirectUrl: string;
/**
 * login
 * @param username the username
 * @param password the password
 */
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const data = '?grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
  let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
  reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(environment.authentificationUserName + ':' + environment.authentificationPassword));
  return this.httpClient.post(PfeUrlConstants.AUTHENTICATION_URL_API + data, {}, {headers: reqHeader})
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return throwError(error.error);
      }),
    );
}

/**
 * get curentUser
 */
curentUser() {
  return this.httpClient.get<User>(PfeUrlConstants.USER_INFOS);
}

isLoggedIn() {
  if (this.storedToken) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

getAuthorizationToken() {
  const currentUser = JSON.parse(this.storedToken);
  return currentUser.token;
}

/**
 * Logout
 */
logout() {
  return this.httpClient.post(PfeUrlConstants.LOGOUT_URL_API,{});
}

/**
 * The client authentication method
 */
clientAuthentication() {
  const data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
  const url = PfeUrlConstants.AUTHENTICATION_URL_API + data;
  let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
  reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Authorization', 'Basic '
    + btoa(environment.authentificationUserName + ':' + environment.authentificationPassword));
  return this.httpClient.post(url, {}, {headers: reqHeader});
}
```

Comment: Heyho, I can't really see an error in your code.
Could you set the `enableTracing` property from the router config?
It will display all the router events and the result of them in your console. alternative you could log the result of `this.authService.isLoggedIn()` in your guard.

Comment: how can i log the result of this.authService.isLoggedIn() in my guard ?

Comment: simply with a `console.log(this.authService.isLoggedIn());`somewhere inside of your guard. I would set it above the corresponding if condition.

If it returns false your login status has not been updated correctly and your problem should be somewhere inside of your `authService`

Comment: console.log(this.authService.isLoggedIn()); return false

Comment: So this method returns false?

Could you post your `authService`?

Comment: I assume that the property `storedToken` is not set.
The constructor is called once and I think that at this time your localStorage have no value. That would explain why you are logged in if you refresh the page.

So I would remove the `storedToken` property and write a small `getStoredToken` method which returns the localStorage value. Alternative you could set the `storedToken` property inside of your constructor and the login method. I would prefer the first approach.

Comment: i think that's the cause of the whole thing.What i want to achieve now is to check if expiration date has passed before accessing the application ?

Comment: for this you could either extend your `isLoggedIn` method and check the expiration date with the current date or you write a second method which handles just this case. 

And then you have to set a guard at your first route to check if the user is logged in and if the token is still valid. If it is valid and the user is logged in you redirect to your needed page.

Comment: i think the best way is to do it inside isLoggedIn function.How can i compare expirationDate and current date to see if the expirationDate has passed ?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your isLoggedIn() of AuthService, just make one change update If condition with this.

```
localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
```

**After Updating your method will look like this**

```
isLoggedIn() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I believe that the variable which you created is initialized ASAP when you consumed AuthService in component, So initially it will be undefined that's why condition always return false